# Invert mouse pointer directions / movements

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, touchpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 14 has mouse buttons integrated in the touchpad and they work very miserably. However, the touchpad has real buttons at its top, which I could use after rotating it by 180 degrees. However, in addition I would need to invert the x and y directions of the mouse pointer in order to make the touchpad work normal after rotation.
Is there a why to reverse the mouse movement?
I am also using AutoHotkey in case this helps.

Comment: Have you tried to google? A search for "windows invert mouse" gives me [this SU question](http://superuser.com/q/406502/216982) which seems to have multiple answers with working solutions.

Comment: @MCL Yes and I also tried the solutions to the SU questions you mention, but none of them seems to work well with Windows 10. The Polynomial's Mouse Inverter, the SakasaMouse and the Autohotkey make the pointer stutter and thus unusable. So I still have no solution.